# Add Ruby classes to a module when defined in separate files

Tags: ruby, class, module, scope

I would like to namespace my Ruby classes by putting them in a module. Indeed, this is a good idea if I decide to publish my Ruby gem so that the class names do not clash with existing classes in another gem. I know I can do the following for a class `A::B`:

```
module A
  class B

  end
end
```

However, the above is quite cumbersome in that I need to put all my class definitions into a single Ruby source file in order to scope them under the module. I would rather keep my class definitions in separate source files, much like a Java project, so how can I add classes to a module when they are all defined in separate files?

Comment: You mean, without saying `module A`/`end` in each of the separate files?

Comment: Ruby is fairly unique in that you can "reopen" a module or class and modify it in multiple places (per @mrzasa's answer). Java doesn't allow that sort of thing so it's an unfamiliar concept to many.

Comment: From the documentation for [Modules](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/doc/syntax/modules_and_classes_rdoc.html#label-Module+Definition): _"A module may be reopened any number of times to add, change or remove functionality"_

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The accepted practice in this case is to wrap every file in `module` block

```
# a/b.rb
module A
  class B

  end
end

# a/c.rb
module A
  class C

  end
end
```

Btw. because of the way constant are resolved, it is advisable to use the long form I quoted above instead `class A::B`

(http://blog.honeybadger.io/avoid-these-traps-when-nesting-ruby-modules/).