# How to add to an included module

Tags: ruby

Consider the following code, which would ideally result in me being able to refer to `Shelf::Things::ThingOne` and `Shelf::Things::ThingTwo`:

```
module Things
  class ThingOne
  end
end

class Shelf
  include Things
  module Things
    class ThingTwo
    end
  end
end

Shelf::Things.constants # => [:ThingTwo]
```

The second declaration of `module Things` has overridden the first one. Is it possible to re-open an included module, so that more (e.g.) classes can be nested within it?

Edit: It turns out this isn't actually the question I wanted answered. I've asked a followup, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49262382/defining-nested-classes-both-directly-and-via-include)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The second declaration of module `Things` has overridden the first one

No, it didn't. `Shelf::Things` is a module totally unrelated to `::Things`.

```
Things.constants # => [:ThingOne]
Shelf::Things.constants # => [:ThingTwo]
```

> which would ideally result in me being able to refer to `Shelf::Things::ThingOne` and `Shelf::Things::ThingTwo`

```
module Things
  class ThingOne
  end
end

class Shelf
  module Things
    ThingOne = ::Things::ThingOne

    class ThingTwo
    end
  end
end

Shelf::Things.constants # => [:ThingOne, :ThingTwo]
```

But as it's been hinted at already in the other answers, this is quite unidiomatic, this kind of "inheriting" constants. It is very likely you chose a wrong tool for the job, but it's hard to tell since [we don't know the actual job](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/174926).

Comment: ...oh! I hadn't spotted that, even if I didn't open `Things` directly in `Shelf`, I didn't get `Shelf::Things::ThingOne` from the include. Huh. So - is there a way I can get what I want? Both `Shelf::Things::ThingOne` and `Shelf::Things::ThingTwo`, where `ThingOne` is from including a module?

Comment: @Chowlett see the update, though you might not like the answer :)

Comment: Hmm, I see. I've potentially over-simplified (my actual situation is buried in the guts of a complex Rails app). I'll see if I can produce a minimal example that's closer to the problem I'm actually facing.

Comment: @Chowlett: yep, a [mcve] would be perfect. Ask it as another question, though. Don't completely change this one.

Comment: Yeah, I had thought I had one when I posted, but I was a step or two short of "complete". I'll link when I have it.

Comment: Thank you, yes. Now crosslinked to a better question.

Answer (score 1):

When you include a module to a class, their methods are included, not classes. So after doing what you did, you can use methods from `Things::ThingOne` in `Shelf` instances.

If you want to use `Shelf::Things::ThingOne` and `Shelf::Things::ThingTwo`, you need to nest both declarations in the modules (modules and classes in Ruby can be defined in multiple files):

```
# file shelf/things/thing_one.rb
module Shelf
  module Things
    class ThingOne
    end
  end
end

# file shelf/things/thing_two.rb
module Shelf
  module Things
    class ThingTwo
    end
  end
end
```

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49197182/add-ruby-classes-to-a-module-when-defined-in-separate-files/49197345#49197345).

Comment: "When you include a module to a class, they're methods not classes that are included" - not strictly true. It's as if the module is "pasted in" to the class. So, if `ThingOne` defined a function `foo`, then `Shelf` instances couldn't call `foo`. But `Shelf::ThingOne` would be a class, and `Shelf::ThingOne` instances _could_ call `foo`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are intentionally overriding module `Things`, nesting a `ThingTwo` class inside `Shelf`, asking ruby to look for a constants in `Shelf` class. You don't have to declare the same module twice, try:

```
module Things
  class ThingOne
  end
end

class Shelf
  include Things
  class ThingTwo
  end
end
```

You will get

```
=> [:Things, :ThingTwo, :ThingOne]
```

Comment: That doesn't help - all `extend` would do is place `ThingOne` into `Shelf`'s namespace directly. I don't want that - I've edited the question to make that clear.

Comment: 1) Yes, that much is clear; 2) that's not how Ruby works in other cases - `class Foo; def hi; puts 'Hi'; end; end; class Foo; def bye; puts 'Bye'; end end` works fine; 3) I want to know how I can end up _not_ overriding it.

Comment: @Chowlett sorry I'm new to stackoverflow, my answer was just edited

Comment: No worries about being new. The thing is, if you re-open a class  definition in Ruby, _usually_ you end up _adding_ to the class (as in my second comment). That's obviously not the case here; I want to know how I can make it work.