# Defining nested classes both directly and via include

Tags: ruby

Suppose I'm modelling my home storage system. I have a bunch of different types of `Container`, and I've found that so many of them have ornaments in or on them that I've set up a bit of helper code for that common case.

Among my containers are my `Mantlepiece` and my `Bookcase`. I only store ornaments on the former; while the latter has all of ornaments, and hardback and softback books.

Here's an initial attempt:

```
module Properties
  def has_ornament
    include OrnamentThings
  end

  module OrnamentThings
    module Things
      class Ornament
      end
    end
  end
end

class Container
  extend Properties
end

class Mantlepiece < Container
  has_ornament
end

class Bookcase < Container
  has_ornament

  module Things
    class Hardback
    end

    class Paperback
    end
  end
end

[Mantlepiece, Bookcase].each do |place|
  puts place.name
  puts place.constants.inspect
  puts place::Things.constants.inspect
end

# Output:
# Mantlepiece
# [:Things]
# [:Ornament]
# Bookcase
# [:Things]
# [:Hardback, :Paperback]
```

You can see that the `Mantlepiece` correctly nests `Mantlepiece::Things::Ornament`; but the in-class declaration of `Things` for `Bookcase` means that `Bookcase::Things` only nests `Hardback` and `Paperback`. `Bookcase::Things::Ornament` is missing.

Can I write this neatly so that `Bookcase` can call `has_ornament`, then declare its own set of `Things`, and have all of them nested in the same namespace?

Comment: Still this doesn't quite make sense, I'm afraid. Why do you need to copy _constants_ across namespaces?

Comment: Because I want, given an object which I know to be a type of `Container`, for `object.class::Things` to contain all the types of things that can be stored in `object`.

Comment: (The actual use case involves types of journals in a journal-replay system, but the analogy is pretty close)

Comment: Could you do with a method? `container.class.acceptable_things` or something?

Comment: "Mantlepiece correctly nests Mantlepiece::Things::Ornament" - not __quite__. Through the magic of ruby name resolution, `Mantlepiece::Things` is resolved to `Properties::OrnamentThings::Things`. Mantlepiece never has its own things.

Comment: But you're right, I feel that this should somehow be possible. I'll give it another try later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though your mantlepiece and bookcase both have things, those things are different (because they contain different classes). So they can't just include some common `Things` module; they instead have to define their own separate `Things`, just like you did in `Bookcase` by declaring `module Things`.

```
def has_ornament
  const_set(:Things, Module.new) unless const_defined? :Things, false
  self::Things.include OrnamentThings
end

module OrnamentThings
  class Ornament
  end
end
```

This works because Ruby lets you reopen modules using the same syntax you use to declare them. `has_ornament` defines a brand new `Things` module, which you then open to add more things. If you call `has_ornament` after your custom things it instead skips the creation and adds to the module *you* made (the `false` makes sure we're looking for `Things` only in the current class).

Comment: Ahh, very nice. It's a bit of a shame with the required order of defining; but a little metaprogramming should let me define an empty `Things` on `.included()`, and add to it both from the class definition and `has_ornament`.

Comment: @Chowlett there is no required order. This works whether you call it before or after you declare `module Things`. That's what I was trying to explain :P

Comment: Oh, I see! I managed to read it with exactly the opposite sense. I'll give it a go, thanks!